# Ассоциативный контейнер-отображение

Tags: c++, ооп, контейнеры

У меня есть задание:
Реализовать класс Cursor. Полями являются координаты курсора по горизонтали и вертикали – целые положительные числа, вид курсора – горизонтальный или вертикальный, размер курсора целое от 1 до 15. Реализовать методы изменения координат курсора, изменения вида курсора, изменения размера курсора, метод гашения и восстановление курсора.

Реализовать такой класс для меня не проблема,но вот условие "Использовать Ассоциативный контейнер-отображение" стало для меня чем-то новым,с таким дела не имел. Можете обьяснить что за контейнер такой и какие функции он должен выполнять?

Comment: Ассоциативные контейнеры - это группы контейнеров `map` и `set`. Возможно имелось ввиду что ваш класс должен иметь функционал, чтобы объекты класса можно было хранить в ассоциативных контейнерах? В текущей формулировке задание не понятно.

Comment: Да,тема задания map multimap, но как например можно реализовать метод гашения и восстановления курсора и как тут вообще multimap использовать можно?

Comment: Ну например в словаре можно хранить коллекцию курсоров. И отображать нужный, в зависимости от какого-то условия. Метод гашения и отображения никак не влияет на использование словаря. Ещё можно одним из курсоров использовать "пустой", т.е. отсутствующий курсор.